# What are usual/ typical patterns to implement callbacks in SOME/IP services?

Tags: autosar, automotive

I have a SOME/IP service `A` provided in an AUTOSAR Classic ECU, which gets consumed by a software component `B` in an AUTOSAR Adaptive ECU.

Prospectively there will be more components like `B` on the same and other ECUs, which might also be AUTOSAR Classic.

`B` uses a SOME/IP request to `A` to request a parametrizable monitor activity and stops this with another request.

I need a solution to give the feedback of the parametrizable monitor activity back.

Due to frame losses to be expected in the use-case I have, there needs to be a feedback from `B` to `A` on reception, so `A` has a chance to retry on timeout.

Because the monitor activity is parametrizable by `B` and multiple monitor activities can run in parallel, fields will not work because there is no guaranteed queuing.

My idea now is to have a callback SOME/IP service in reverse direction, which allows to give the feedback via another request.

Either all callbacks would be triggered, or preferred, `B` would provide it's instance ID of the callback service to `A` with it's request to start the monitoring.

Is there are more elegant/ typical/ ... solution?

Because of AUTOSAR Classic being a static system, I will for sure have to define all possible instances of `B` statically, but I would prefer a way in which we do not have to change the source code of `A` when another instance of `B` gets added, but "only" have to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I read the question all wrong, but wouldn't the simplest solution be to send events from A (which, as far I understand the question, is in the server role) to B?

Comment: Oh, I will add this to the question.
Frames might get lost due to the use-case of this service, so there needs to be some feedback to be able to retry after timeout.